# send a json array and receive it as a jaxb jersey parameter of type List

Tags: arrays, json, jaxb, jersey

Hello I am sorry if already asked but couldnt find.

Here is my problem, I do not know how many fields i will send to my webservice as they will be dynamic. As such i wanted to send a json array to my jersey jaxb ressource. as the objects in my json array will be a single dimensional array of strings i should be able to do the below:

```
  @POST
    @Path("/test")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response InputList(@QueryParam("list") final List<String> inputList)
```

Here is my json array
{
"list": [
    "hello",
    "world"
]
}

This does not seems to work....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you have now doesn't work because your JSON doesn't represent a list of strings. It represents an **object** that has a single property which is a list of strings. To wit:

```
["hello", "world"]
```

Is a simple JSON data stream that can be deserialized directly into a `List<String>` in Java. Whereas:

```
{"list" : ["hello", "world"]}
```

Is a more complex data stream that needs to be deserialized into an object, for example one that looks like this:

```
public class ListHolder {
    private List<String> list;

    // constructors, getters/setters
}
```

You can then use this in your Jersey resource:

```
@POST
@Path("/test")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response InputList(@QueryParam("list") final ListHolder listHolder) {
    final List<String> list = listHolder.getList();
    // rest of code
}
```

Comment: @Fongios - thats a totally separate question and should be posted as such.